# Why canceling of call doesn't work in Vidyo lib

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-conferencing

We are developing application for conference calls and we are using Vidyo framework for it.
Apart of Vidyo we have build own web server for making connections.

We have face the following issue: 
If caller is reaching receiver using web API and then canceling call using Vidyo lib - receiver won't get any notification about canceling event.
But it works if caller reaching receiver through Vidyo API.

How can we solve the issue we stuck at?

Thanks, Tony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should organise connections queue on your web server.
So, each call and cancelation should be registered on your web server and put in a queue.

I had similar issue and solution above helped to get it work.

Good luck ;)

Comment: I had talked with guys - makes sence. Thanks.